# Origin of the numpy and pickle new memory error?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, memory, pickle

I am facing a problem when I want to create my training set of images for deep learning. Images are 299x299 grayscaled .tif files. Each category has almost 3000 images. I used to compile thoses datas in pickle file that was about 6.5 Go. Then I managed to load it without any problem.

However, I recently want to work again with this training set, and when I ran the exact same code than before I have this memory error :

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
import random
import pickle

DATADIR = "path/to/folder"
CATEGORIES = ["A", "B","C","D"]

training_data = []
IMG_SIZE_H = 299
IMG_SIZE_W = 299

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        

        list_dir = os.listdir(path)

        list_dir[:] = [item for item in list_dir if '.tif' in item]

        for img in tqdm(list_dir):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE_H, IMG_SIZE_W))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            
create_training_data()

random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)
    
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE_H, IMG_SIZE_W, 1)

X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 299, 299, 1).astype('float32')

pickle_out = open("X_train.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out, protocol=4)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("y_train.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 299, 299, 1).astype('float32')
>
> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 6.06 GiB for an array with shape
> (18204, 299, 299, 1) and data type float32

Besides, I kept the old pickle file (which size is 6.5 Go) and when I tried to load it in the same exact CNN as previously, I also have a memory error :

```
X_train = pickle.load(open('X_train.pickle', 'rb'))
```

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 X_train = pickle.load(open('X_train.pickle', 'rb'))

It is very weird because I haven't change anything, same computer, same python version (3.7), same images, same code, same versions for pickle and numpy (only tensorflow was updated but I do not see any link).

I have the feeling that something goes wrong with the memory of my computer itself, but I have always used the same computer for the previous code.

Please, could you let me know if you have any clue that can explain or solve this problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MemoryError` is an out of memory exception.

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 6.06 GiB for an array with shape (18204, 299, 299, 1) and data type float32

Can you check that you have `>7 gb` of ram available?

Comment: Hi @JunkyByte ! Thank you for your answer. As you suggested, ram was very low (for unkwown reasons). After restarting the computer, code works fine (always remember basics of debugging ^^)